# Microsoft Edge crashing on startup

Tags: crash, microsoft-edge

I configured edge to always reopen last opened session. Upon startup, edge is crashing and it fails to open. I tried opening edge in private (inPrivate) mode and it's opening fine. This means that the problem is most probably that the tab which edge tries to load on startup is crashing and causing edge to crash.

How can I, from disk, open edge without restoring last opened session? How can I open a clean edge? How can I reset this edge configuration?

*PS: Repeated questions to make it easier for users suffering to find this question*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `C:\Users\\{YourUser}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Preferences` (a json file), open in text editor and find the entry `ROOT.session.restore_on_startup`, change the value from 1 to 0.

This will clear the "restore last opened session" configuration only once, when you open the edge, and it will fix the problem.

Next time you close and reopen edge, the flag in Preferences file will be automatically re-set to 1.

Answer (score 1):

this is another silent launch crash cause that only happened to me on Win10 after a recent Edge update.  this was worse in that there was no way to start edge, removing user profiles etc didn't work, and it would even crash trying to uninstall Edge, so you were hosed.

In the MSVC debugger I could see it was crashing trying to read Chromium Policies during startup.

the cause was some registry Edge policy restrictions set by O&O's 'Shutup10++' (https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10), which stops Windows tracking you in various ways.  I've been using this for years, so either there were out-of-date settings, or something changed along the way - but those settings still work fine with the old 104 Edge versions.  The policies are stored in:

HKCU\Software\Policies\Edge

renaming 'Edge' to something else allows Edge to start again.

I didn't have the patience to figure out exactly which one causes it, but here are the bad ones I had (=crash) vs the good ones I recreated with the current ShutUp10++:

[old/bad settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvoC0.gif)

[new/good settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXuoa.gif)

Comment: Edge started doing this when it updated to 106.0.1370.42